# How to compile rust packages with different targets

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

Lets say I have nested packages like `/foo/bar`

Now I want to compile these packages with different targets.
So, How to compile `/foo` package with target `wasm32-unknown-unknown`and `/foo/bar` package with target `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` with one build command like `cargo build --release`?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the default target (that will be used absent an explicit `--target` option on the command line) in a [configuration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) file.  I therefore suggest that you create the following files:

1. `/foo/.cargo/config.toml`

   ```
   [build]
   target = "wasm32-unknown-unknown"
   ```
2. `/foo/bar/.cargo/config.toml`

   ```
   [build]
   target = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
   ```

To ensure that `/foo/bar` is built whenever `/foo` is built, you can use a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html):

`/foo/build.rs`

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=bar");

    let profile = std::env::var("PROFILE").unwrap();
    let status = std::process::Command::new("cargo")
        .arg("build")
        .arg(format!("--{}", profile))
        .current_dir("bar")
        .status()
        .expect("failed to execute cargo");

    assert!(status.success(), "failed to build bar");
}
```